# Exclude custom filter for some URL in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2, servlet-filters

I have a spring boot application that uses OAuth authentication. On top of authentication, I need to authorize the user before they can access the system. I have created a custom filter that will authorize the user. I just want to run this filter only after `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. If `BasicAuthenticationFilter` does not run then my filter also should not run.

**AuthorizationFilter.java**

```
@Component
public class AuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        boolean isValidUser = true;
        // we get the authenticated user from the context
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String id = (authentication == null)? "" : authentication.getName();

        ..
        // code to get the user data from database using 'id' and set isValidUser flag
        ..
        if(isValidUser) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
        else {
            ...
            // handle UNAUTHORIZED
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {

        security.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable();

        security.cors();

        // Custom filter to validate if user is authorized and active to access the system
        security.addFilterAfter(new AuthorizationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Even if I have permitted '/actuator/health' endpoint my custom filter still runs for that endpoint. How can I exclude my filter from running on '/actuator/health'?
2. The perfect solution would be to run my filter only if `BasicAuthenticationFilter` runs. Is this possible? How?

Comment: In your AuthorizationFilter `final String header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (header != null && header.startsWith("Basic ")) 
        { put your filter code or filter buisiness logic } chain.doFilter(request, response);`

Comment: It should solve your problem.

Comment: So basically I have to check if there is any token provided or not. Is that if I get the same as if I get 'authentication' object as null, I should not run my filter?

Comment: Same case as is in BasicAuthenticationFilter

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the best solution for these kinds of issues is to create a new filter chain. In your case, there would be a filter chain for endpoints that need authentication and another filter chain for endpoints that are open (do not need any authentication).
Here is the sample filter chain for unprotected endpoints:

```
<bean id="openFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain">
    <description>Pass the list of filters that you want to invoke for the given request matcher.</description>
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="infoRequestMatcher"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <list>
            <ref bean="exceptionTranslationFilter"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="infoRequestMatcher" class="org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher">
    <description>
        Pass the request matcher that matches all you unprotected endpoints.
    </description>
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="/actuator/health"/>
</bean>

<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <description>
        Register your custom filter chain here.
    </description>
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="openFilterChain"/>
            <ref bean="otherSecurityFilterChain"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```